# изучаю "Наследование", возникает ошибка

Tags: c++, наследование

Объясните пожалуйста, где ошибка ?
Пометил комментариями ошибку. За пример взял перегрузку операции.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Counter
{
protected:
    int count;
public:
    Counter():count(0)
    {}
    Counter(const int t):count(t)
    {}
    void get_count()
    {
        cout << count << endl;
    }
    Counter operator + (Counter t2)
    {
        return (this->count + t2.count);
    }
};

class NewCounter :public Counter // писать здесь protected Counter и все равно не помогло
{
public:
    NewCounter(int c): Counter(c)
    {}
    Counter operator -(Counter t2) 
    {
        return (this->count + t2.count);
        //ошибка в t2.count, пишет: "не удается получить доступ к защищенному члену Counter::count"
    }
};

int main()
{
    Counter t1(5), t2(4), t3;

    t3 = t1 + t2;

    t3.get_count();


    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все правильно, переменная `count` доступна только внутри класса для использования, у получившегося экземпляра его не будет. В данном случае объект `t2` приходит извне и является экземпляром и у него нет свойства `count`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Рекомендуется передавать аргумент в функцию (оператор) по ссылке а не по значению. Вот так:

> Counter operator + (Counter& t2)

2. Странный оператор вычитания в NewCounter реализует почему-то сложение.
3. Собственно ответ на вопрос. Доступа к члену count у типа Counter вне его методов нету так как член протектированный. Сделайте вот так:

> ```
> Counter operator -(NewCounter& t2) 
> {
>     return (this->count + t2.count);
> }
> ```

4. Если нужен оператор вычитания (сложения?) именно с Counter то либо надо объявлять друга либо вводить функцию доступа get. Либо делать открытым член count (не рекомендуется).

UPD1:

Подумал немного как сделать оператор сложения для NewCounter и Counter без друзей и функции доступа get а только с помощью конструкторов инициализации. И вот что получилось:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> class Counter{
> protected:
>     int count;
> public:
>     Counter():count(0){}
>     Counter(Counter& cnt):count(cnt.count){}
>     Counter(const int t):count(t){}
>     void get_count(){cout << count << endl;}
>     Counter operator + (Counter& t2){
>     Counter ret(this->count + t2.count);
>     return ret;}
> };
>
> class NewCounter :public Counter{
> public:
>     NewCounter(int c): Counter(c){}
>     NewCounter(NewCounter& cnt):Counter(cnt.count){}
>     NewCounter(Counter& cnt): Counter(cnt){}
>     NewCounter operator +(NewCounter& t2) {
>     NewCounter ret(this->count + t2.count);
>     return ret;}
>     NewCounter operator +(Counter& t2) {
>     NewCounter ret1(t2);
>     NewCounter ret(this->count + ret1.count);
>     return ret;}
> };
>
> int main(){
>     Counter t1(5), t2(4), t3;
>     NewCounter t4(3);
>     NewCounter t5(0);
>
>     t3 = t1 + t2;
>
>     cout<<endl<<endl<<"t3=";
>
>     t3.get_count();
>
>     t5 = t4 + t2;
>
>     cout<<endl<<"t5=";
>
>     t5.get_count();
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Здесь немного переделано форматирование, чтобы пример занимал поменьше строк. Операторы все сделаны как операторы сложения. В операторах сложения введены явно возвращаемые значения нужных типов. И введены конструкторы инициализации. Проверялось на http://cpp.sh/ и на https://gcc.godbolt.org/ транслятор x86-64 gcc 7.2.